# Trash missing from Dock

Tags: macos

I can't find my Trash folder on my Mac — it isn't on my Dock and I really don't know where to find it. I'm new to OS X.
Does anyone know where I can find my Trash? I can put items in my Trash, but I want to empty some files not all of the files that are in there.

Comment: Bottom right corner of your screen, on the doc bar?

Comment: That's the problem I don't see it there!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to delete the Trash folder from your Dock. To put it back, reset your Dock settings:

1. Open Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
2. Run the following command to delete the Dock preferences file:

   ```
   rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
   ```
3. Log out and back in.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first use `killall Dock` using Terminal.

This will reset your dock. If this doesn't work then you should download a 3rd party application such as DragThing.

Then logout and log back in, and start using DragThing.

If you need more help you can go on these websites : http://mac.bigresource.com/OS-X-Leopard-System-and-Trash-icons-gone-from-dock--t9R58eDJO.html

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1494553?tstart=0